# ajax redirect not working

Tags: java, redirect, jsf-2

This is my jsf code :-

```
  <h:commandButton id="cmdLogin" value="Login" actionListener="#{indexBean.login}">
                            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@all" />
                        </h:commandButton>
```

This is my login method of indexBean :-

```
 public void login(){

                HttpServletResponse objHttpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
                objHttpServletResponse.sendRedirect("Restricted/Home.jsf");

    }
```

I get one alert in javascript `emptyResponse: An empty response was received from the server.  Check server error logs.`. Why does this type of redirect not work?

**EDIT :-**
Interestingly, when i redirect from faces-config.xml, it works!

```
<faces-config version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>Home</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/Restricted/Home.jsf</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

And obviously, i changed `actionListener` of commandbutton to `action` and changed return type of `login` to `String` and returned `home` from login method. Can anybody tell now, if this is the desired behaviour in JSF ? How come redirect  from `faces-config.xml` works and simple redirect in managedbean doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpServletResponse objHttpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)
                              FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                          .getExternalContext()
                                          .getResponse();
objHttpServletResponse.sendRedirect("Restricted/Home.jsf");
```

Here, you leave the JSF API and cast down to the servlet API where JSF will not handle anything you do. When you invoke this method, the server returns a [302 response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) instead of the AJAX response the JavaScript API was expecting.

The correct mechanism to perform a programmatic redirect in JSF is to use the [ExternalContext](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html):

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext()
            .redirect("yourUrl");
```

If you use this mechanism with an AJAX call in JSF 2.0, the server will send a response like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<partial-response><redirect url="yourUrl"></redirect></partial-response>
```

You can use tools like [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_(web_development)) and [Fiddler](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Fiddler_%28software%29) to inspect your server's responses.

---

*Note that this method signature is incorrect: `public void login()`. The specification states that action methods must declare an object return type (the fact that your implementation doesn't throw an error just means you got lucky).*